# Opening app from background Android

Tags: java, android

I have created an Android app that I am also running on BB10 devices. It has some functionality regarding call logs, but one of the most important functions is that the app has to open (assuming it's in the background currently) whenever a phone call has ended. Worded differently, it needs to foreground itself whenever a phone call has ended. I currently have it creating a dialog that opens within the app, but it will not appear until the app has been manually foregrounded. I do not have a requirement as to how it opens itself, but I do need a yes / no dialog to appear when it does.

Is there any way to have the app auto-open itself? Or is that not possible?

Comment: use info by this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838230/ways-to-bring-an-android-app-in-background-to-foreground

Comment: ps. i guess, no need to tell that this should be deployed in broadcast receiver registered for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` intent

Comment: @mangusta that seems to have solved it! Not sure how to mark this question as solved or give you credit though.

Comment: that's not necessary, I'm here to help, not receive credits : )