# How can I bring an activity to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, screen

If my activity is doing something in a background thread and now I want to display that activity in the foreground (because there's an alarm or something important to show), how can I do it?

I've seen this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892632/1121497) but it creates a new activity.

I want to display the existing activity to the user, even when the user is using another app or even when the screen is off (here I know I'll need to use a `WakeLock`).

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424488/android-new-intent-starts-new-instance-with-androidlaunchmode-singletop

Comment: Thanks Rafael, but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe because I start the activity from the same activity? --- Yes, Mark, but that's the requirement. It's a special safety app that displays an important warning.

Answer (score 3):

I used the first solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12075313/1121497) but started the intent using the application context like it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892632/1121497), so the final code would be:

```
protected void bringActivityToForeground() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, getClass());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

I added that to my `BaseActivity` class.

In case you need it, you may also use a `WakeLock` to turn the screen on.